# How to translate partial HTML text with i18next?

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, i18next

Complete i18next noob here, so bear with me!

My HTML is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li><a href="#">Sección 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sección 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sección 1.3</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="Doc" name="Doc" data-i18n="[placeholder]mykey" placeholder="Document" />
```

and I load my translations with this javascript code:

```
i18n.init(
    {
        lng: $.cookie("i18next"),
        fallbackLng: "es",
        debug: true,
        resGetPath: "dist/js/i18n/___lng__.js",
    },
    function (t) {
        $(document).i18n();
    }
);
```

How can I declare my `data-i18n` tags on every `li` so I only have to provide a single key for the "Sección" piece of inner HTML and preserving the 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to add `data-i18n` tag into your html

```
<a href="#" data-i18n="menu.home">Home</a>
```

I've made an example for you:

[link to my jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yaxofuhuzu/1/edit)

here are other sample usage that you can consider:
http://i18next.com/pages/sample.html

or if you are looking for nested usage, you can use `$t()`

for example:

```
'en-US': { 
    translation: { 
      'menu': {
        'taipei': 'Taipei, $t(menu.country)',
        'tainan': 'Tainan, $t(menu.country)',
        'kenting': 'Kenting, $t(menu.country)',
        'country': 'Taiwan'
      }                           
    } 
  }
```

I've updated the jsbin. Hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks Jim, I was already aware of that, but you're translating the whole keys. In your jsbin, you see the problem right there: you're repeating the "Taiwan" substring three times, between parentheses.
I'd like to provide "Taiwan" only once and compose your "menu" children with the specific strings and ONLY ONE single block for "Taiwan"

Comment: sorry, I'm not quite understand what you mean. If you would like to specify it once, you can use the array method. I've updated the jsbin for you to see:

http://jsbin.com/vocucatuje/1/edit

is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok. I mean something like this, for specifying "taiwan" only once:

`'en-US': { 
    translation: { 
      'menu': {
        'taiwan-name' : 'Taiwan',
        'taipei': 'Taipei (' + taiwan-name + ')',
        'tainan': 'Tainan (' + taiwan-name + ')',
        'kenting': 'Kenting (' + taiwan-name + ')',
      }
    } 
  }`

Comment: updated the jsbin example, hope that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks! answer marked as accepted. Although it's specified in the i18next docs (following your link), the explanation is a little sparse.
Your jsbin is not (yet) updated, but the example works perfectly fine. Thanks again!

Comment: and if I need to change the value of a param? <a href="HERE" >Home</a>